# Playing live http stream in vlcj

Tags: java, audio-streaming, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm trying to use vlcj to play live internet radio stations in a project. I've played around with some sample programs for a few hours, but I cannot get either the sample programs or programs that I've played around with to play the stream from the URL.

An example of a URL I'm trying to play is: http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/wmp/live.asx?service=vr

Is there anything special I have to do in order to get vlcj to play this stream? I couldn't find anything to help in the API. (Assuming it can because it can be played through the VLC media player!)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the MRL you have provided us http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/wmp/live.asx?service=vr is a MMS server that may pull a ASX (XML) metafile which may contain at least one sub-item.

http://all-streaming-media.com/faq/streaming-media/Metafiles-ASX-Advanced-Stream-Redirector.htm

To be able to play this type of streaming media and go through each sub-item, you need to do the following code snippet:

```
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().setRepeat(true);
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().setPlaySubItems(true);
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().prepareMedia(media, options);

try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

for(String s: VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().subItems()) System.out.println(s);
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().play();
```

For the example MRL above, it will list down all sub-items as follows:

```
http://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/g1/absoluteradio.co.uk/prerolls/ar_account_1310455302_hi.wma
mms://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/absoluteradio.co.uk/vr_lo?u=
http://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/absoluteradio.co.uk/vr_lo?u=
mmsu://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/absoluteradio.co.uk/vr_lo?u=
mmst://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/absoluteradio.co.uk/vr_lo?u=
mms://wms.absoluteradio.co.uk/absoluteradio.co.uk/prerolls/problems_lo.wma
```

To stop playing all of them, set the following code snippet:

```
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().setRepeat(false);
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().setPlaySubItems(false);
VideoPanel.getMediaPlayer().stop();
```

For a better explanation, refer to: http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/HowToHandleYouTubeMedia

Comment: This is the solution I eventually went for and it worked successfully!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the http to play such link directly.  You will ve to use the port number of the radio station router.  this is because if i want to receive my home live video streaming from the internet at my workplace, i type the following on url:  http://my dns server ip address:8080   The 8080 is the port number I opened on my router.